# Why is req.body undefined when im using a body parser?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

My req.body object keeps being undefined even though I've used app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));. At my html all my inputs have "name" attribute given and they match what I've written in this code. Can you help me solve this? Thank you.

JavaScript Code:

```js
//Constantes
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const passport = require("passport");               
const session = require("express-session"); 

//---------------
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");   
//const passport = require("passport");           
const passport_local = require("passport-local");
const LocalStrategy = passport_local.Strategy;
const connection = require("./database");  
//-----------------


//Config
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.engine(".hbs", exphbs.engine());
app.set('view engine', ".hbs");

//--------------------

passport.use("local.signup", new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: "email",
    passwordField: "password",
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async (username, password, req, done) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    const user = { email: username, password: hash, nombre: req.body.nombre, apellido: req.body.apellido};
    const result = await connection.query("INSERT INTO usuarios SET ?", user);

    user.id = result.insertId;
    return done(null, user.id);
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {  
    return done(null, user.id);
 });
 passport.deserializeUser( async (id, done) => {    
     const rows = await connection.query(`SELECT id, email FROM usuarios WHERE id = ${id}`)
     return done(null, rows[0]);
 });

//-----------------------------------
//require("./passport");
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(session({
    secret: "secreto",  
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));
app.use(passport.session());
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("listening on port " + port);
});

app.use(require("./routes/index.js"));
app.use(require("./routes/register.js"));
```

Html form that the users sees (all the "name" attributes match as they should):

```html
<!-- Formulario de registro -->
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-content-center m-5">
        <h1 class="text-center mt-5">Registro Administrador</h1>
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <form action="/register" method="post" class=" border border-2 border-dark p-4 rounded">
                <div class="form-group p-2">
                    <label for="email">E-Mail <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                     <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="marcos@example.com" required name="email"  value="{{ email }}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group p-2">
                    <label for="password">Contraseña <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                     <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="*********" required name="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group p-2">
                    <label for="nombre">nombre <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                     <input id="nombre" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="nombre" required name="nombre">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group p-2">
                    <label for="apellido">apellido <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                     <input id="apellido" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="apellido" required name="apellido">
                </div>
                <div class="d-grid p-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark outline">Registrarse</button>
                </div>
                <div class="d-grid p-2 ">
                    <a href="/login" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark outline">Ya tenes cuenta? Logeate!</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Where's the frontend code that submits the data to your backend?

Comment: Im adding it right now. Thank you

Comment: Where are you seeing that `req.body` is `undefined`? Is it that `console.log(req.body)` in your `passport.use()` handler?

Comment: Yes, there. Im also having trouble when trying to access to "req.body.nombre" and "req.body.apellido" at the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#parameters), the order of parameters passed to the `LocalStrategy` callback are...

> req, username, password, done

With that in mind, your code should look like this

```js
passport.use(
  "local.signup",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    async (req, username, password, done) => { // req is the first parameter
      console.log(req.body);
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
      const user = {
        email: username,
        password: hash,
        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        apellido: req.body.apellido,
      };
      const result = await connection.query("INSERT INTO usuarios SET ?", user);

      return done(null, result.insertId);
    }
  )
);
```